# Как правильно сделать запрос к БД с функцией Scan()?

Tags: mysql, golang

Надо получить значения из нескольких полей_А таблицы, из записи, у которой в поле_Б значение "х".  Компилятор не ругается, но при работе выдаёт общую ошибку запроса: `expected 1 destination arguments in Scan, not 2`.  Вразумите, в чём проблема, и как правильно написать.

Код:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/link", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var dataDB struct {
        nameUser_colm string
        oldUser_colm string
    }
    
    err = db_ss.QueryRow("SELECT `nameUser` and `oldUser` FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_B` = codeLink").Scan(&dataDB.nameUser_colm, &dataDB.oldUser_colm)
    
    fmt.Sprintf("Из таблицы: имяЮзер - %s; возрастЮзер - %s", dataDB.nameUser_colm, dataDB.oldUser_colm)   // Тест.

    // Общая ошибка запроса.
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Query error:", err)
        return
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT `nameUser` and `oldUser` […]
```

Не `AND`, а `,`:

```sql
SELECT `nameUser`, `oldUser` […]
```

Comment: И всё??! Пишет же ошибку про Scan(). Или это именно из-за непрпавильного синтаксиса SQL-запроса?

Comment: А как `Scan` по-вашему работает?  Посылает ваш запрос на БД.  БД отдаёт результат с одной колонкой, а не двумя.  `Scan` в шоке.  Ну и «Мускуль» тоже хорош как всегда.  Нормальная БД нормальную ошибку [выдаёт](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1PnmBPpvWGtzvgK4yTAR1/0).

Comment: Понял. Спасибо! :)